# Why does (boolean ^ int > 0) work?

Tags: java, syntax

When you try to do something like this:

```
if (true ^ 1) {
  //do something
}
```

the compiler reasonably says that operator `^` is not defined for argument types boolean and int.
But if you use it like this:

```
if (true ^ 1 > 0) {
  //do something
}
```

the code compiles (for Java 8 at least) and flawlessly works.
Basically these operations:

```
false ^ -1 > 0 
false ^ 1 > 0
true ^ -1 > 0
true ^ 1 > 0
```

Act like a valid logical XOR:

```
     | ^
-----+--
 F F | F
 F T | T
 T F | T
 T T | F
```

Could anybody please explain what happens under the hood?

Comment: I recommend you learn about [*operator precedence*](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/11precedence/).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude To be fair, the fact that bitwise operators have lower precedence than comparisons is a particularly unintuitive aspect of the operator precedence of languages where it's the case.

Comment: Which is why you need to learn about it, @random :-)

Answer (score 78, accepted):

It's simple: `>` has higher [precedence](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) than `^`, so

```
if (true ^ 1 > 0) {
```

is equivalent to

```
if (true ^ (1 > 0)) {
```

which is equivalent to

```
if (true ^ true)
```

... which is just logical XOR.

I would never *write* code like this, mind you. I would be surprised to see an example which couldn't be written more clearly in a different way.

Comment: I never got why safety oriented languages like Java and C# even allow such code, instead of requiring parentheses for clarity. After all, there is no rule that operator precedence must be a total order.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: Well predence + associativity make the behaviour well-defined for any expression. I'm not sure whether that's what you mean by "total order" though...

Comment: @CodesInChaos I think the answer is that the are 'safety' oriented and not 'clarity' oriented.  These are related but distinct.  Safety requires that there be no ambiguity and this is definitely unambiguous.  The idea of a clarity-oriented language is interesting though.  I've never worked with something that restricted syntax _purely_ because it might be hard to understand. It is sort of odd since clarity is widely considered to be such a fundamental aspect of good development.

Comment: @JonSkeet: I believe what CodesInChaos means by "total order" is that Java need not define either `^` or `>` as having higher precedence. The language could be defined such that using both in the same expression, without parentheses, would be a parse error. For instance, Haskell allows defining operators in this way: it would say "Precedence parsing error: cannot mix ‘^’ [infix 5] and ‘>’ [infix 5] in the same infix expression."

Comment: @wchargin: Ah, I see - no rule of language design. Yes, I agree with that. That doesn't mean that total order *is* necessarily a bad thing.

Comment: @JonSkeet I just wanna see what your points look like once you hit 1 million!! LOL +1 It's 925K now so will it be 1m when you get to that point or what.

Answer (score 11):

Because operation `>` has higher priority than `^`, so it is equivalent to `true ^ (1>0)` which is operating with same types (boolean ^ boolean).

Comment: [It is "than", not "then"](http://www.wikihow.com/Use-Than-and-Then) (in this context).

Answer (score 10):

1 is of type int.

1 > 0 is of type boolean.

^ means XOR; and you can't XOR boolean and int.

In other words: the first expression "1" evaluates to a number; the second expression "1> 0" evaluates to boolean logic. The reason behind that is the operator [predecence](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html).

Answer (score 3):

Because order (priority) of operations is important, `>` has higher priority than `^`

Here, first we check `1 > 0` and then first operation is XORed (`^`) with first result

Is equivalent to `if(true ^ (1 > 0 ))`

But, of course You can't XORed boolean with int